# Angular dist on http-server - offline installation

Tags: angular, deployment

I have to run Angular 7 dist on an offline server [server has no connectivity outside - security restrictions].
I thought to install http-server and just run **http-server ./dist**.
The problem is that the server can't reach to the web, so I can't install http-server via npm install !
I can download the http-server from GitHub, so I can copy that
folder into the server manually.
The question is how can I run on it an Angular app [dist].
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Clone it from github from to another pc, install all dependency and move it in the offline environemnt: https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/1349

Comment: even i have same requirement,still not able to find any relevant answer.Did u find some thing?